# Is it possible to proxy websocket connections with mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

Currently, I have an Apache web server configured to respond to `myserver.com`. Additionally, I have a second web server application listening on port 4321 in localhost on the server. I want this web server to respond to `api.myserver.com`.

If possible, I would prefer to rely solely on `.htaccess` present on `public_html/api.myserver.com`.

Currently, I have both `http` and `https` working with the following `public_html/api.myserver.com/.htaccess` rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} ^(ws|wss)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) ws://localhost:4321/$1 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} !^(ws|wss)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:4321/$1 [P,L]
```

However, when I try to connect using the `ws`/`wss` protocol, it does not work. My guess is that the proxy [P] flag is not upgrading the connection to `ws`.

Is there an equivalent for `.htaccess` comparing to `ProxyPass` like the one below?

```
ProxyPass "/some/ws/capable/path/" "http://example.com/some/ws/capable/path/" upgrade=websocket
```

Comment: Does the `ws://` prefix imply a port number? A browser seeing `http://` will routinely assume port 80, `https://` will go to port 443, `ftp://` to port 21. Are you sure that you have Apache listening to the correct port?

Comment: `If possible, I would prefer to rely solely on .htaccess.` - There's a complete cargo cult of people endlessly using  .htaccess files when they shouldn't. Please don't be another one. The [manual recommends](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when) ***"use of `.htaccess` files should be avoided when possible"*** - Second: there are several examples and condition here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

Comment: @tsc_chazz `ws://api.myserver.com/ws` should proxy to `ws://localhost:4321/ws` so if I understood correctly, no the `ws://` does not imply a port number. As far as I know ws protocol are normally listen to the same http/https port (ws/wss respectively)

Comment: @HBruijn I know that I should not rely on `.htaccess`, however I have not full control of the server. `mod_proxy_wstunnel` has a deprecation warning: `Since Apache HTTP Server 2.4.47, protocol Upgrade (tunneling) can be better handled by mod_proxy_http.`. Indicating that `ProxyPass "/some/ws/capable/path/" "http://example.com/some/ws/capable/path/" upgrade=websocket` should be used.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the actual name of the server in your redirect instead of `localhost`? I note that the ProxyPass statements you've quoted use a hostname.

Comment: @tsc_chazz I don't think so because this 2nd webserver is only listening to the loopback ip (localhost), is not accessible to the public (only via the proxy), so `myserver.com:4321` is not responding.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that you open that port to the public IP, just as a test, and change the redirect to `myserver.com:4321`. If it works, then the problem is that `localhost`. If not, we can look for something else. But I've been burned a few times thinking that a `localhost` redirect would work that way, and found it didn't.